# Update: :Extension: Could not open https://update.joomla.org/core/sts/extension_sts.xml

Tags: joomla, updates

Joomla update error ,
Update: :Extension: Could not open https://update.joomla.org/core/sts/extension_sts.xml
 Does any one know how to reslove this issue

Answer (score 4):

Well followed this method to fix it in Joomla 3.5.0, it was caused due to https,

1) Go to Joomla update , will get a error as above.

2) with above page open , simultaneously Go to Joomla database , in table db_update_sites , search for 
https://update.joomla.org/core/sts/extension_sts.xml

3) Replace https://update.joomla.org/core/sts/extension_sts.xml
with http://update.joomla.org/core/sts/extension_sts.xml

4) Then click update in front page, It gets updated .

Comment: You are a hero, thank you! For me the entry was in the table `jos_updates` where `jos_` is the prefix my Joomla installation uses for all tables.

Answer (score 0):

It's a server problem check if **allow_url_fopen** is set to true, or the **fsockopen** function is enabled. Otherwise, exit from the server may be blocked.

Comment: Thanks Rinos. Well solved using a trick , the error was due to Https://protocol,