# Issue with update joomla from 2.5.17 to 3.5.1

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I am trying to upgrade Joomla from 2.5.17 to 3.5.1 from administrator panel.

In the options of "Joomla Update" I have selected "Short term support" and this is the error message that I get:

**"Could not open [https://update.joomla.org/core/sts/extension_sts.xml"](https://update.joomla.org/core/sts/extension_sts.xml%22)**

[image]

How can i do for this issue and update my joomla?

Comment: You could check if the upvoted answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46974668/update-extension-could-not-open-https-update-joomla-org-core-sts-extension is helpful

Comment: And you should consider posting your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.